# Mixing Dynamics and Generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing a function in C#. My function needs to determine the range for a set of values based on their type. I will be supporting more types in the future which is why I want a generic function. For now, I'm just considering `Int32` and `DateTime`. Currently, I have the following:

```
private void GetRange<T>(List<Value> list, out dynamic absoluteMin, out dynamic absoluteMax, out dynamic begin, out dynamic mean out dynamic finish)
{
  T tempMin = default(T);
  T tempMax = default(T);

  begin = tempMin;
  if (tempMin is Int32) 
  {
    absoluteMin = Int32.MinValue;
    begin = Int32.MinValue;
    finish = Int32.MaxValue;
    absoluteMax = Int32.MaxValue;
  }
  else if (tempMin is DateTime)
  {
    absoluteMin = DateTime.MinValue;
    begin = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
    end = DateTime.Today;
    absoluteMax = DateTime.MaxValue;
  }

  foreach (var item in list)
  {
    var value = item.Value;
    if (tempMin is DateTime)
    {
      // ...
    }
    // determine begin and end of values in the list
  }
}
```

I call this method like this:

```
dynamic min = null;
dynamic max = null;
dynamic start = null;
dynamic end = null;

var useInt = ShouldIUseInt();
if (useInt)
  GetRange<Int32>(myList, min, max, start, end);
else
  GetRange<DateTime>(myList, min, max, start, end);
```

When the method is called, it throws a runtime error that says the following:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'myClass.GetRange<System.DateTime>
(System.Collections.Generic.List<Value>, out object, out object, out object, out object)' 
has some invalid arguments
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this runtime error or how to fix it. any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are missing a comma in your function definition, and also it expects 5 out parameters, not 4.

Comment: First, the title of this question made me immediately say "oh no!!!". Second, why are you using `dynamic` here anyway? What's wrong with `object`? You don't seem to be accessing any properties of the arguments sent in anyway. Or why not use the generic type parameter `T`?

Comment: Also, instead of having one method with a giant if-else construct (or a switch case) you could use different overloads for each type. Just because it *possible* to do this using generics does not mean that generics are the *best* solution.

Comment: So what happens when `T` is `long`, or `bool`, or anything that isn't `int` or `DateTime`? This doesn't look like a legitimate use of generics.

Comment: You could just use LINQ's `Min` and `Max` methods to get the range: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352408(v=vs.95).aspx  That works for any class that implements `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable` or for many primitive types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to go down this route of combining different purposes into that single function.  A better approach would be to make a generic out of your results and then create an extension class that will aggregate your results.

```
using System.Linq;

public class Range<T>
{
   public T Min { get; private set; }
   public T Max { get; private set; }

   public Range(T min, T max) 
   {
      Min = min;
      Max = max;
   }
}

public static class RangeExtensions
{
    public static Range<T> GetRange<T>(this List<T> values)
    {
        return new Range<T>(values.Min(), values.Max());
    }
}
```

You would be able to call this on any list containing comparable primitive types and types that implement `IComparable<T>` like this:

```
 List<int> intList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
 List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), DateTime.Now.AddDays(5) };

 var intRange = intList.GetRange ();
 var dateRange = dateList.GetRange ();
```

Comment: That's what I get for speccing out code on one computer and then hand typing it here.  Fixed the issues.

Comment: Now why should we iterate on the values twice to find max and min. A simple foreach loop would be enough to find both.

Comment: It's an example, the signature and approach for calling is more important than the way the range is calculated.

Comment: @people,  if `signature and approach` is good then why don't you upvote this answer?